# RSS Feed "Updating Too Often"

Tags: php, cakephp, rss

this may or may not be a silly question but I know little of the mysterious ways of RSS feeds, so hopefully someone can put me straight!

I have a website with an RSS feed of news items.  A user has complained that the feed is updating crazily frequently, without any change in the top 5 news items displayed.

I'm ashamed to say that I don't use RSS feeds much personally, so I don't even really know what it implies for one to be "updating too often" - I can see how it would be annoying, if you keep checking an "updated feed" only to find no new content, or even worse if you are receiving continual alerts of non-existent updates.  But as I say, I don't have a clear picture of how RSS feed consumption generally works.

The next question is, if the way our site is generating its RSS feed is a problem, what can I do about it?  The top news items aren't changing incredibly frequently.  It's possible, but not certain, that automated scripts are updating items in the database that are related to news items, though even still, I can't imagine how this would be happening "crazily frequently".  RSS feeds, how do they work?  Would a re-generation of the top news items count as an update for everyone's RSS readers, even if the top news items are to all intents and purposes exactly the same as before?

If it's relevant, the RSS feed is being generated by standard CakePHP helpers for the purpose.

Anyone have any insights into RSS issues of this sort, and can put me on the right track to a solution?

**EDIT:** Okay, I subscribed to the feed using Safari as the default RSS reader and indeed, over the course of the afternoon I had two identical copies of each news item in my inbox.  I'm pretty sure no new "real" news items are being generation, so something must be registering with the RSS readers as an update, and I don't know what.  My question may not have been very clear (argh, downvote) but it still stands!

Comment: an RSS feed is just some specific XML. Hit the feed's URL in your browser and see what it's saying the refresh intervals should be. There's a few specific fields in RSS that define how frequently things should be refresh. It could be that the feed's misconfigured and saying "refresh every 5 seconds" or whatever.

Comment: Could you give us the url of the feed? What format is used ATOM,RSS 1.x/2.x

Comment: Do you have both a guid & the actual pubDate in your feed (not just 'right now')?

Comment: RSS version appears to be 2.0.  guids and pubDates seem to be present and correct on items, and the latest pubDate is a couple of days ago, so I can't how that would result in constant crazy updates.  Working on finding something that designates some refresh intervals!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An RSS feed is a feed that can be parsed(understood) by computers easily. There are more than enough sources explaining RSS(XML). Like for example this wiki page about RSS has [an example of a feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS#Example).

If I understand you correctly he is subscribed to a feed that gets updated every time an update(news) is created. He finds this happens more often than he would like and he likes to have a feed containing only the most important news items. So if I understand you should provide a new different feed(another url) to the most popular updates.

I would also like to inform you about [PubSubHubBub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/)(hubbub) to make your feeds realtime. When the consumers(who like to parse your feed) are using hubbub protocol this information is pushed(gets delivered) instead of polling(asking all the time if there is any new information available probably without any new information being available).

Comment: Hmm, well, new news items are not being created very often, that's the thing I find a little strange.  But it's possible that the page is being regenerated too often in some way.  I'm going to check out the various suggestions/requests for further data and get back to you.  And also take a look at your hubbub link!

Comment: You should provide us a link to check it out I guess. It is hard to answer without that information...

Comment: Good point. http://4ad.com/news.rss. I'm pretty stumped as to what could be going wrong, I may know shamefully little about RSS feeds but I don't think we've done anything too silly or controversial.

Comment: also most of the times feeds are summaries. http://pastebin.com/mXs4SJGj is a part of your feed for example that is not that fine to read. Most of the times the feeds are more plain. I am saying a lot of markup, javascript, junk in the feeds...

Comment: Hmm, yes, there could be valid "good style" concerns there - initially it's just a direct feed of the news items as they come, no attempt made to tidy them up for RSS consumption.  I'll have to look into that, after we solve this "too frequent update" issue!